# how get selected radiobutton value in constructor

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a vf page which have two radio button Yes or No. I want selected value in constructor after clicking on submit buton.
here is code.

```
 <apex:page controller="CCO_ScheduleACallController">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:outputLabel style="Bold">Are you able to launch your software or service?</apex:outputLabel>
<apex:selectRadio value="{!radiovalue}">
          <apex:selectOption itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="1"></apex:selectOption>
          <apex:selectOption itemLabel="No" itemValue="2"></apex:selectOption>
      </apex:selectRadio>
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
<apex:commandButton action="{!Submit}" value="Submit"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Since in the exisitng contrroler most of the logic is implemented in constructor. And now i have to add condition
IF(selected value=='Yes')
{
//code
}
else
{
// code
}

Comment: You should put your logic in submit merhod, as contructor is getting called during initialization.

Comment: The Submit button's action isn't executed until after the constructor. You should refactor your controller to move logic out of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor will call at the time of page loading.But note that we cant do to any dml operation on constructor. for example if submit method contains any dml operation you will get error(so you can handle it in action method!!)

I believe you are setting default value. That default value you can access in server side and also you can change that value in constructor( please check selected value)

```
  public class CCO_ScheduleACallController{
  public boolean selectvalue {get;set;}
    public CCO_ScheduleACallController(){
     selectvalue=false;

    }
```

Comment: We will never get user selected value from current page in constructor.

Comment: This code is not valid. `submit()` returns a `PageReference`, and you have an undefined variable in your `submit()` method.

Comment: ya. I agreed but i believe he is passing default value (thats not user selected value)

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. You can't get user selected value in constructor.First constructor  run then User get result on UI. You can set any value from Constructor which will display to user.

```
 public class CCO_ScheduleACallController{
    public CCO_ScheduleACallController(){

         radiovalue = '1'; // user will get Yes pre selected
    }
```